# IBM Worklight - "System.NotSupportedException" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Hi I am using Worklight to develop application for Windows Phone 8. The application was working fine, however when I applied the Fix Patch for Worklight the Windows Phone Console started to give me below error :

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

The other error is

> Error:"Unable to get property 'content' of undefined or null reference file:x-wmapp0:/www/skinLoader.html Line:1"

Any one has any idea why these two errors started coming all of sudden?

Moreover, where can I change Worklight specific properties in Visual studio?

Comment: Please always mention the Worklight version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Moreover, where can I change Worklight specific properties in Visual
>   studio?

There are no "Worklight specific properties" in Visual Studio.

Once you build the Worklight project in Eclipse and open the result (in your case, the generated Windows Phone 8 project) in Visual Studio, that's it - it is a Windows Phone 8 project.

> Error:"Unable to get property 'content' of undefined or null reference
>   file:x-wmapp0:/www/skinLoader.html Line:1"

Try to:

1. Delete the native folder in Eclipse from the `your-project\apps\your-app\windowsphone8` folder
2. Re-build and deploy the application
3. Re-open it in Visual Studio

---

As for the SystemNotSupportedException message, this can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks Idan , I tried the steps you provided. But it didn;t work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I seem to be getting this exception again, but the application continues to work properly; if everything works, I suggest to ignore it.

Comment: Should I also ignore the SystemNotSupportedException as well?

Comment: Again, if the app works in device and simulators, then I suppose so.

Comment: the error is still coming , but as per your advised I ended up ignoring it. Windows Store accepted it, the application even made it to their feature app list. So I guess we are safe to ignore, if you can edit your answer and add the ignore the error part, I would certainly mark it as accepted solution :)